# grails unit test mocking not working with spock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spock, grails-3.0

I'm trying to mock a redisService and its method.  I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Basically I'm getting a null pointer in the service code because the stubbed out smembers() method is returning null instead of the mock Set below. Any ideas?  thx.

```java
void "test findAnagramsForWord happy path"() {
    given: "a test word and a mocked service"
       String word = "read"
       Set mockSet = new HashSet()
       mockSet.add("read")
       RedisService mockRedisService = Mock()
       mockRedisService.smembers(_) >> mockSet
       service.redisService = mockRedisService
    when: "anagramService.findAnagramsForWord is called"
       def anagramMap = service.findAnagramsForWord(word)
    then: "Expect to equal a certain product of prime numbers"
       anagramMap.anagrams.length() == 2
}
```

Comment: Where do you define mockRedisService ?

Comment: I thought in this line, no? RedisService mockRedisService = Mock()

Comment: You could use GroovyMock() instead of Mock()

Comment: You do not show where `service` is defined, how it uses `redisService`, what types of objects `anagramMap` and `anagramMap.anagrams` are. You have not posted any stacktraces either. It would be nice to have something reproduceable, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), either in your updated question or on GitHub.

Comment: service is by convention referring to the service spec I'm testing.  I agree though, I prob should have given more info.  Evgeny, using GroovyMock() totally worked!  I have no idea why, but it did.  Thx guys.